# The road to El Dorado reconstructed from fragmented accounts

Tags: word, wordplay, no-computers

*You are seeking the route to the lost city of El Dorado.  You have assembled several historical accounts from explorers who claim to have reached it.  Unfortunately, the accounts are incomplete, fragmented, or evasive.  None provide all the milestones necessary to chart the route to El Dorado.  Your only certainty is that the milestones which were reported are correct and in the proper order.  Can you reconstruct a complete route from the fragmented accounts?*

We're going to do something similar, but through a word puzzle.

RETAIN, HERO, STATION, CHEST, and ORCA are all examples of "fragments" taken from the source word ORCHESTRATION.  Notice that letter ordering in the source word is preserved in the fragments.

I'm going to give you a set of "fragments" and we'll see if you can reconstruct the source word.  I have designed it so that the given words are sufficient to determine the source word, but not easily.

For example:

```
Given words:

CRAM
CUTLET
TIN


-----------------------

Solution:

CURTAILMENT
```

If you're having difficulty seeing it, here is a graphical demonstration:

```
C   R   A     M   
C U   T     L   E   T
      T   I       N 
---------------------
C U R T A I L M E N T
```

It sort of looks like word Tetris!

As always, I construct my puzzles in such a way that they can be solved using only well-known words, so if you find yourself conjuring up increasingly obscure words, you may be overthinking it.

See if you can figure out the source word for each of these eight sets of "fragments" below:

```
1.  AUTO
    STRAIN

2.  CAKE
    FIERCER
    FREAK

3.  COURT
    MINUTES
    RUINS

4.  COLAS
    SCOTCHES
    SHOOTERS

5.  SEND
    SPROUT
    SUCCOR

6.  CANTON
    CONTAIN
    OCEAN

7.  LEGIT
    PORES
    TRESS

8.  PRUDE
    SEANCE
    URBANE
    (okay, maybe the source word for this one is just a little bit... professorial)
```

Comment: Very nice puzzle concept, and well executed!

Comment: SlowMagic, I love all of your word puzzles! They're always very creative and fun

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT:  I think I got them all!

1)

> SATURATION

2)

> FIRECRACKER

3)

> MICRONUTRIENTS

4)

> SCHOOLTEACHERS

5)

> SUPERCONDUCTOR

6)

> CONCATENATION

7)

> POLTERGEISTS

8)

> SUPERABUNDANCE

Comment: I thought #1 was AUSTROHUNGARIAN, I like yours better.

Comment: I was on nationalities for a while too, something about the letters...