# El Dorado Word Puzzle II: Videogame Edition

Tags: wordplay, video-games

Let's keep going with the [El Dorado puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/80716/the-road-to-el-dorado-reconstructed-from-fragmented-accounts).

Same rules apply.

Given a set of common words, can you figure out which videogame title they cover?  All letters in the title must be covered, and letter order must be maintained.

For example:

```
Given words:

    AFT
    EMOTE
    ERR
    TOSS


=================================

Solution:

    TEAM FORTRESS


because


        A   F     T
      E   M   O   T   E
      E         R   R
    T         O         S S
    -----------------------
    T E A M F O R T R E S S
```

Videogame titles can be long and wordy.  I have removed the spaces in between the words, as well as punctuation, sequel numbers, and Roman numerals.  Other than that, I have shown you no mercy.  So, if the title is "Destructo Sisters III:  Fire Fists of Fury" you will be looking for DESTRUCTOSISTERSFIREFISTSOFFURY.

See if you can solve these:

```
1.  JURY
    ONE

2.  EARBUD
    EON
    THUD

3.  REFIT
    SEETHE
    TIGER

4.  MOD
    PETRI
    SURE

5.  BOON
    LOBE
    ODOR

6.  HOOT
    TERRA
    TOENAIL
    TOGA

7.  ABOVE
    ALCOVE
    HOOTED
    MALE

8.  ERROR
    MOOD
    SPRAWL
    SUPERIOR

9.  BRAWN
    BROKEN
    RUTTED
    UNTO

10. RARE
    SWIFTER
    TASTE
    WEIGH

11. MOOD
    PARODY
    PRISSY
    SUEDE

12. EONS
    GEL
    LEAFED
    LUGE

13. EARL
    LAID
    MAGES
    TROD

14. FACT
    FANATIC
    FIFTY
    INLAY
    STATS

15. EAGLE
    NODE
    PRONG
    ROAN
    SALE

16. EMAIL
    PARLAY
    PROXY
    SERIAL
    UGLY
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Complete solution** - combining with answers from Jaap Scherpuis and APrough and comments by El-Guest and Birjolaxew

1.

> Journey

2.

> Earthbound

3.

> Street Fighter

4.

> Super Metroid

5.

> Bloodborne

6. solved by Jaap Scherpuis (see their answer)

> The Oregon Trail

7. solved by Jaap Scherpuis (see their answer)

> Halo: Combat Evolved

8.

> Super Mario World

9.

> Burnout 3: Takedown

10.

> Star Wars: TIE Fighter

11. solved by El-Guest in the comments

> Super Mario Odyssey

12. solved by APrough (see their answer)

> League of Legends

13.

> Metal Gear Solid

14. solved by Jaap Scherpuis

> Final Fantasy Tactics

15. solved by Birjolaxew

> Persona 4 Golden

16.

> Super Mario Galaxy

Comment: 11 I think is the same as 8 and 16 except r13(bqlffrl)

Comment: @El-Guest Thank you, I figured it was probably related.

Comment: If numbers are allowed, 15. could be [rot13(Crefban 4 Tbyqra)](https://pastebin.com/Nnk1pFWx)

Comment: @Birjolaxew Thank you, I knew there was such a game series but didn't realise what this one was called.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis — I worked hard to make sure there was no ambiguity.  For example, TEAMFORTRESS contains two "E" letters, but the "E" in ERR can only match with the first one.  If it were matched with the second one, then the "R" would have nothing to match to.

Comment: @Birjolaxew — You're on the right track.  I removed numbers and numerals prior to extracting the clue words.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis — Qualifying my previous comment:  the clue word is extracted from left to right.  In the very rare cases in which the same letter could have been extracted from two different positions without affecting the extraction of the subsequent letters, it chooses the leftmost.  (That's why double letters in the solution word always require double letters in a clue word.)  So you are correct, there is room for a little bit of ambiguity!

Comment: @SlowMagic All I meant was that when letters occur multiple times non-consecutively in the answer, it can confuse you during solving if you pick the wrong matching. Once you know the answer, the clue words can be easily checked against it as the matching is then obvious. Thanks for explaining how you made that matching unambiguous, as that is a wrinkle I hadn't considered. (Note: For some reason my comment was removed when this thread was cleaned up.)

Answer (score 8):

Here are some that hexomino missed.

6.

> The Oregon Trail

7.

> 1 Halo: Combat Evolved

14.

> Final Fantasy Tactics

Comment: Nice work, Jaap +1

Answer (score 6):

10.

> Star Wars: TIE Fighter

12.

> League of Legends